# Band Combination for NIR-R-G in Landsat 7 scene

Tags: image-classification, band, landsat-7

What is the order for the band combination to show Landsat7 scene in NIR-R-G Band? The band combination I used is:-

[image]

And the result generated is:-
[image]

Is this the correct layer combination to show Landsat-7 scene in NIR-R-G Band?

Comment: What do you want to analyze by using the NIR band? For e.g. vegetation analysis it's typically like you did it: The NIR Band on the red channel, blue on blue and green on green. But in general it doesn't matter you can also put the NIR band on the blue or green channel.

Comment: @Radde1683; Yeah, I need to analyze vegetation, waterbodies, open soil and buildings. Does their combination differ for waterbodies, open soil and buildings.

Comment: Can't have a better explanation than this https://web.pdx.edu/~nauna/resources/10_BandCombinations.htm